# AR.js to show png hanging on the wall

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, ar.js

I have an e-commerce website where I sell illustrations from different independent artists.

I have an idea where the user turns on the camera and see how a poster (png file) looks in their wall, using the web browser of their mobile.

Is this achievable with [AR.js](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js) or this is something achievable only with a native mobile app?

If so, could you share some guidance for me to start looking into?

Thanks you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, using a browser and webcam, and of course some JavaScript.

One way is to have the end user print out a marker with a defined pattern that you can then replace with an image. The [Image Texture example at this URL on GitHub](https://stemkoski.github.io/AR-Examples/) contains almost exactly the code you want, running in a browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you if can it be done without having the user to print a Marker? I imagine that maybe the user can touch wherever they want to put the image, standing right in front of the wall.

Answer (score 2):

With ARjs you can only do it if the user has a marker on their wall. You can have the users printing markers as part of your user journey. I think a better solution for you will be [model-viewer](https://modelviewer.dev/). Model-viewer can recognize surfaces and add your models to this surface, the problem is that if you want to present a png, you can't. what you can do is convert this png to a 3D model (just a plane really) and present that.
You can also check out [echoAR](https://www.echoar.xyz) (full disclosure - I work there), and see if there are any solutions that work for you with ARjs/ model-viewer.

Hope it helps.